# Compare same temporary table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have save data in temporary table (`#Result`).

If I was input parameter it can show me different information for example,

List A Contains:

```
ID        FirstName 
-------------------
123       Peter
456       Ben
789       Eric
```

List B:

```
ID      FirstName 
-------------------
123     Peter
888     Jack
999     Mary
```

When generating both List A and List B, if FirstName, ID has both appear, How to do that details of such FirstName, ID will be excluded from List B and show in List A only (avoid duplication).

I think I can use `not exists` to delete List B (123  Peter) but how to compare the same temporary table.

Below is my query. Thanks a lot!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].xxxxx
    @List varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #Result
    (
        iList char(1),
        [ID] nvarchar(100),
        [FirstName] nvarchar(100),
    )

    IF @iList LIKE '%A%'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Result
            SELECT
                iList = 'A',
                [ID] = ab.[ID],
                FirstName = ab.[FirstName]
            FROM
                xxxx
    END

    IF @iList LIKE '%B%'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Result
            SELECT
                iList = 'B',
                [ID] = ab.[ID],
                FirstName = ab.[FirstName]
            FROM
                xxxx
            WHERE 
                NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Result 
                            WHERE b.id = a.id)<----(not sure);
    END

    SELECT * FROM #Result
END
```

Expected result:

List A:

```
ID        FirstName 
-------------------
123       Peter
456       Ben
789       Eric
```

List B

```
ID      FirstName 
-------------------
888     Jack
999     Mary
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the results you want.

Comment: Also I would highly recommend working on your layout and using consistent casing as it makes your query much easier to understand. And your aliases aren't correct.

Comment: @Gordon The Result added.Thanks you  for  your teaching!

Comment: @Dale thanks you for your adivse.I will pay more attention!

Comment: Your question doesn't show your `where` clause on your base table, `xxxx`, but you must have one - please update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend understanding table aliases. You alias the table, then use the alias to refer to that table. So if, for example, you alias `xxxx` as `X` then you use `X` to reference that table from then on. And in your sub-query you need to alias the table with a different alias e.g. `R`. Now best practice is to use a letter or two which represent your table name which is why I have used `X` and `R`, however you should change them to suit your real table names.

```
insert into #Result (iList, ID, FirstName)
    select 
        iList = 'B',
        [ID] = X.[ID],
        FirstName = X.[FirstName]
    from xxxx X
    where not exists (select 1 from #Result R where R.id = X.id);
```

Here is a fully working [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5e9a7fbc2f982187f1fe81675f981dbc) based on the information provided which returns:

| iList | ID | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | Peter |
| A | 456 | Ben |
| A | 789 | Eric |
| B | 888 | Jack |
| B | 999 | Mary |

In future please consider setting up your questions in this format with DDL/DML statements to build your sample data followed by your attempt and then expected results. Your question will be much clearer and easier to answer.

Comment: it's work! All my tables use the same alias so will appear error .thank you for your patient teaching!

Comment: Sorry Dale, i think it still not work, i find duplicate record/3\cry

Comment: Hello Dale, I am very thankful that you reply me quickly. The query show "Invalid column name 'id."

Comment: Temporarily follow your alias, OMG, so difficult, cannot find the problems, btw Thank you for your continued support and where is your dbfiddle??thxthx

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is right. The doubt you still can't understand is

> how to compare the same temporary table.

I think you must get know the concept for dataset.
Database do not compare(or even use) the data directly in table. It takes out the data from the table which data store on the disk named tablespace file to the memory. The dataset is the data your SQL let database query out.

Comment: Thank ElapsedSoul explanation! but when i exec the query it show the error "The multi-part identifier "A.ID No" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "B.ID No" could not be bound."

Comment: ```from xxxx
            where not exists (select 1 from #Result where b.id = a.id)``` to ```from xxxx a
            where not exists (select 1 from #Result b where b.id = a.id)``` knowledge about table alias.@ericso

Comment: it's work! All my tables use the same alias so will appear error .thank you for your teaching. Your message let me know more!

Comment: sorry ElapsedSoul, i think it still not work, i find duplicate record/3\cry